# Elapsed Time Interpretation in Oracle AWR Report

Tags: oracle, administration, awr

In my AWR (automated workload repository) report, I see the following

**Free Buffer Waits : 24,000 seconds**

I have a 4 CPU machine.

Does this means there was 24,000/4 = 6,000 seconds of "clock time" or "real time" wait ?

Answer (score 0):

This 24000 seconds is the sum of all Sessions wich are waiting for "Free Buffers". If you have 100 Sessions and 1 hour AWR-Report, it means that each Session was waiting 240 Seconds per Hour for Free Buffers (on average).